# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to run a LINQ query on an DbSet and cannot get the following line of code to compile:

```
return db.ListOfThings.Where(i => i.IsProd && !i.Inactive);
```

Both `IsProd` and `Inactive` are properties, so I know I'm not missing parentheses. I can put the exact same query on a List<> and it works as I expect it to.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can I see the signatures for those two properties?

Comment: Kindly specify what error are you getting while compiling it.

Comment: One of them is a method and not a property. My guess, `IsProd` is missing `()`

Comment: I'd start by looking at the implementation for IsProd and Inactive just to make sure one of them is not a method. I've had times myself where I thought something was a property only to find out it had been implemented as a method.

Comment: I trust compilators. IsProd is a method.

Comment: "Both IsProd and Inactive are properties"  No, they are not.  Only one is.  If they were, then you wouldn't be getting that error that's specifically telling you that one of those two is a method.

Comment: Oh, just found it. It turns out IsProd IS a function. Weird that it works in another LINQ query but not this one.

Comment: @NorwegianWood Then you were either invoking it in that query, or using it in a context where a method group, rather than a boolean value, was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out IsProd is a function. It just happens to work differently in another LINQ query I have. From Servy: Then you were either invoking it in that query, or using it in a context where a method group, rather than a boolean value, was expected.